# Value of a ksh variable

Tags: shell, ksh

Let's take this through example. An example ksh script is as below:

```
ab=123
c=a
d=b
echo "${c}${d}" # prints ab, but need to print contents of $ab ie. 123
echo "$ab" # prints content of $ab i.e. 123
```

How can I print content of varible formed through  `"${c}${d}"` i.e. content of `$ab` thus formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use eval to achieve this:

```
eval y='$'${c}${d}; echo $y
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `ksh93` then you can use the `nameref` feature (from [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#line-111):

```
# ab=123
# c=a
# d=b
# typeset -n ref=$c$d
# echo "${!ref} = ${ref}"
ab = 123
```